# Why do actual website display before redirecting to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, redirect

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $.get('https://ipinfo.io/json?token=391fde43dafbc6', function (response) {

            if (response.country == "UK") {
                window.location.href = "http://www.secondwebsite.com.pk/";
            }
        });
    </script>
```

it redirects to another page but first the actual website displays for few seconds. I dont want to display it. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your site displays because `$.get` is **asynchronous** - therefore, the code inside the $.get callback won't be executed until after the page loads (at least partially)

To avoid displaying anything until you may have to, have your `body` with CSS `display:none`, and only display it if you are not redirecting

e.g.

```
<body style="display:none">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.get('https://ipinfo.io/json?token=391fde43dafbc6', function (response) {

            if (response.country == "UK") {
                window.location.href = "http://www.secondwebsite.com.pk/";
            } else {
                document.body.style.display='';
            }
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: my script is directly inside the html so instead of body i did the same for Html tag. Correcy?

Comment: doesn't matter what you hide/show, didn't think it was as easy to do that with the html tag, but if it works, then it's just the same thing - the location of the script doesn't matter